# Different methods for type casting in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the difference between:

```
Car(someObject).isRacing;
```

and

```
(someObject as Car).isRacing;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionScript: Is there ever a good reason to use 'as' casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996478/actionscript-is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-as-casting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an earlier thread on this same topic, you'll find lots of details in there.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996478/actionscript-is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-as-casting/997055#997055)

Answer (score 7):

Casting using `Car(someObject)` will throw an error if someObject is not of type Car or does not extend Car, whereas `someObject as Car` will merely return null if some object is not of type Car or extends Car.